# Search in .net MVC with AJAX. What can I do for the following code?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, search

I want to do a search with AJAX. I simply did with the get method through passing search string in controller but that not I want

Below my controller code, where I get the search value from URL and return DATA (which is a list)

```
if (search != null)
    {
        if (search.ToLower().ToString() == "paid")
        {
            DATA = DATA.Where(a => a.Purchased_Price > 0).ToList();
        }
        else if (search.ToLower().ToString() == "free")
        {
            DATA = DATA.Where(a => a.Purchased_Price == 0).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            DATA = DATA.Where(a => a.Purchased_File_Name.ToLower().StartsWith(search.ToLower()) || a.Purchased_Category.ToLower().StartsWith(search.ToLower()) || a.User1.Email.ToLower().StartsWith(search.ToLower()) || a.Purchased_Price.ToString().StartsWith(search)).ToList();
        }
        ViewBag.SoldList = DATA.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, pageSize); *this is what I actually did*
        return Json(DATA , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); *this is trial I do not know this work or not*
}
```

*Below is the script which I wrote in view. Where I am going wrong? I'm not aware of that. I want whatever list comes with the help of whatever search I entered. To be printed in the table. Table is just above this script; I don't think it's needed so I did not include that.*

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search_button").on("click", function () {
            var search_value = $("#searchText").val();
            alert(search_value);
            var SetData = $("#tabledata"); *tabledata is id of tbody tag *
            SetData.html("");
            console.log("setddata");
            console.log(SetData);
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "/Home/MySoldNotes?search=" + search_value,  *home is controller, mysoldnotes is action*
                contentType: "application/ json; charset = utf - 8",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log("result");
                    console.log(result);
                    $.each(result, function (index, value) {
                        var data = "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + value.NoteDetail.File_Name + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + value.Purchased_Category + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + value.User1.Email + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + value.NoteDetail.Sell_Price + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + value.Req_Solved_Date + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>"
                        SetData.append(data);
                    });
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert("Error aa gai");
                    console.log(err.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass object to controller from ajax call. Example

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search_button").on("click", function () {

        var objParam = new Object();
        objParam.search_value = $("#searchText").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/MySoldNotes"
                contentType: "application/json; charset = utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(objParam)
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log("result");
                    console.log(result);
                    $.each(result, function (index, value) {
                        var data = "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + value.NoteDetail.File_Name + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + value.Purchased_Category + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + value.User1.Email + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + value.NoteDetail.Sell_Price + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + value.Req_Solved_Date + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>"
                        SetData.append(data);
                    });
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert("Error aa gai");
                    console.log(err.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then in your controller

```
public JsonResult MySoldNotes(string search_value) 
{
   // Do whatever and return json as result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<BuyerReq> DATA = dc.BuyerReqs.Where(a => a.seller_id == ab && a.Status == true).AsQueryable().ToList(); 
return Json(DATA, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

while returning from the controller I am getting an error(not success my AJAX call).

but when I am doing this for testing purpose :

```
var aa = "checking"; return Json(aa, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

this works. I am not getting the exact error.